# flutter ServerSocket unbind tcp

Tags: flutter, dart, bind, serversocket

here is my code in statefulWidget Class that i push from main class,the code belove work well the first time ,but when i try to open the second time i receive bad stream , stream was listen to ,so i find a lot on google to unbind ServerSocket or dispose it,but i don't find nothing.

```
@override
void initState(){
  listenToEvent();
  super.initState();
}

void listenToEvent(){
  finale server =ServerSocket.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4,4000,shared:true);
  server.listen((socket){ // here was the exception start for the second time
      handleConnection(socket);
  });
}

void handleConnection(Socket client){
  client.listen(
    //here read very well all data
  );
}
```